# Modelo conceitual

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, modelo-relacional, diagrama, entidade-relacionamento

Estava vendo os diagramas de modelo conceitual, vi alguns que contém os Atributos e Entidades como este:

[image: DER]

E outros que só tem a Entidade:

[image: DER simplificado]

Qual modelo está correto? ou os dois estão?

É necessário identificar os atributos no ER Conceitual? ou posso somente ter as Entidades e os relacionamentos entre elas?

Caso seja necessário declarar os Atributos, o que se faz quando uma Entidade possui uma quantidade enorme de Atributos, tipo uns 30 ou mais?

Comment: Desculpe a pergunta, mas o Modelo Conceitual à que se refere não é o mesmo que o MER (Modelo Entidade Relacionamento)?

Comment: Sim, esse mesmo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem [várias notações de diagramas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model), cada uma com sua característica. Nenhuma está errada, mas cada uma pode ser mais adequada que outra. Depende da intenção que se deseja demonstrar.

Particularmente eu acho que o [modelo conceitual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_schema) deve ser bem simples e deixar os detalhes para o modelo lógico que tem uma notação mais fácil para organizar os detalhes.

Em geral quando se coloca atributos nas entidades no modelo conceitual coloca-se apenas o estritamente necessário para ajudar entender os relacionamentos ou outras coisas fundamentais. Mas nada impede de colocar tudo, ambos estão corretos.

Alguns autores consideram errado colocar atributos no modelo conceitual. Outros dizem que pode, desde que não use termos técnicos.

Então quem está certo? Faça o que for útil para você e não se preocupe se alguém disse que está certo ou não. O importante é ter algo que ajude. Tem gente que precisa do modelo conceitual, lógico e físico, com bastante detalhes. Tem gente que se vira só com o físico.

É possível ter um documento separado que auxilie o diagrama conceitual com mais detalhes.

Lembre-se que o modelo conceitual não é muito técnico, ele deve ser de fácil leitura por um leigo em computação. Esta é a principal diferença do modelo conceitual e o lógico que já é um pouco mais técnico, mas ainda um pouco abstrato.

Um dicionário de dados sofisticado pode ajudar mapear isto. Infelizmente não há boas ferramentas no mercado para isto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

O **Modelo Entidade-Relacionamento** propõe que a realidade seja visualizada sob três pontos de vista, a saber:

**a)** os objetos que compõem a realidade,

**b)** os tipos de informação ou características que se deseja conhecer sobre os objetos que compõem a realidade e

**c)** a forma como estes objetos interagem entre si.

Desta forma, **o Modelo Entidade-Relacionamento é composto por três conceitos: Entidade, Atributo e Relacionamento**. Os objetos que compõem a realidade são as Entidades. As características que se deseja conhecer sobre os objetos que compõem a realidade são os Atributos. A forma como os objetos interagem entre si constitue o Relacionamento.

Assim sendo, suas duas primeiras perguntas me levam a mesma resposta: SIm, ambos os modelos estão corretos, sendo o primeiro melhor. Quanto mais detalhes você adicionar de forma correta e coerente ao modelo conforme nos ensina a teoria, melhor será o entendimento/compreensão/facilidade para o desenvolvimento. Lógico que todo esforço a mais deverá condizer dentro de uma linha custo-tempo-resultado, mas não vou entrar nesses detalhes que fogem a questão...

Quanto ao **atributo**, aprendi que:

**a) Identificação**: A identificação de cada atributo deve ser composta por um substantivo singular e, se for necessário, mais um qualificativo que o caracterize. Devem ser utilizadas letras maiúsculas. *Por exemplo: NOME, DESCRIÇÃO, DATA DE NASCIMENTO*

**b) Definição**: Cada atributo deve receber uma descrição sucinta do seu significado para a Organização. Além disso, a descrição de um atributo deve ser complementada com um “data type” local ou global que o caracterize. *Por exemplo: NÚMERO DE MATRÍCULA (INT, 05).*

Ou seja, se esses atributos estão com muitos caracteres é porque existe algo que contradiz o ítem A da nossa teoria. Assim sendo, seria melhor rever a identificação dos mesmos.